# Databases in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

How can i improve the speed of a query i did.The data retrieving takes too long,and i think is my problem cause the SQLite Admin do the same a lot faster, Here is a piece of my code:

```
public Cursor getContacts(String search)
    {        
     Cursor c;       
     String[]columns = {Constants.USER_NAME,Constants.PHONE_NUMBER};
     String Limit = "0,20";
     String query = search != null ? Constants.USER_NAME + " LIKE '" + search + "%' " : "";

     c = myDataBase.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME,columns, query, null, null, null, null, Limit);

        return c;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you tagged your question with python/django, but here's my answer:

First of all, how long is your query taking? It might take quite a while to ask such an open question to the database. Measure the time using e.g. System.currentTimeMillis() like so:

```
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
//run your code here
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Time: " + (t2-t1));
```

My suspicion is that your problem might be that you are running in the UI thread of your app, which might crash if the query takes too long.